# Setting up server side rendered angular app in plesk

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering, plesk, angular-universal

I have setu server side rendering in my angular app using nguniversal and it is working fine in my local where I can serve the files using

```
npm run serve:ssr
```

which will run the following command

```
node dist/moviesplay/server/main.js
```

How can I implement this in my remote server with plesk?

I tried using the plesk nodejs extension and set the application root and startup file as follows

```
Document Root /httpdocs/angular/dist/moviesplay/server    
Application Mode production  
Application URL ********
Application Root /httpdocs/angular/dist/moviesplay/server   open  
Application Startup File main.js
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfvwW.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deploy angular universal on Plesk panel (apache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027188/how-to-deploy-angular-universal-on-plesk-panel-apache)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The document root folder which is the angular files must be inside application root folder.

Basically the server folder must be the parent directory of UI folder

It worked for me.

Comment: Can You please share screenshot ?
I want to know what you set it in Document root & Application root

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the Document Root folders

```
Document Root /httpdocs/angular
Application Mode production  
Application URL ********
Application Root /httpdocs/angular 
Application Startup File dist/server/main.js
```

Comment: I've tried this one but unfortunately it did not work.. My nodeJs server on Plesk refuses to start server side.. Any other suggestions? 

Thanks in advance!
R

Comment: Do you have Proxy server on with ngenx?