# How to deploy angular universal on Plesk panel (apache)

Tags: angular, apache, plesk, angular-universal

I have problem with running **Angular Universal** on my **Plesk** panel (apache):

already i insalled `nodejs`:

[image]

1. i do `npm run build:ssr` on my localhost and copy the `dist` from localhost to `httpdocs` directory on plesk.
2. copied `package.json` on `httpdocs` directory;
3. **in this step what i should do ?**

> I clicked on `Run script` in my Plesk and try to run `serve:ssr`, but nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-make sure in your "Document Root" to choose the browser folder in dist.

-in your server.ts REMOVE this if condition:

```
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}
```

and replace it with just:

```
run();
```

then restart your node.js app again from the plesk GUI

Comment: Thanks to you my friend, helpful answer.

Comment: Hi! I followed all your steps, thanks by the way, but when I press Run Script and I put "serve:ssr" it fails saying "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000", but I don't have anything alse running with node on my server... Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get this working? I having similar isses

Comment: @IñigoGorosabel I'm having the same problem, any luck?

Comment: what's the problem you having @colouredFunk??

Comment: I don't know exactly what did I do but I have it working now. I switched it to use nginx only, set up a Node application on that domain (Document root /httpdocs/dist/browser Mode production Application root /httpdocs and Start script dist/server/main.js) and everything works now. I also did what the answer says here.